# Параллельная сортировка пузырьком на C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Всем доброго времени суток. Несколько часов убил на то, чтобы понять, как работают потоки на C#, однако ничего толком не вышло.

В качестве примера выбрал сделать параллельную сортировку пузырьком, вот код:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Задаем целочисленные переменные
        int n, buf;
        Console.WriteLine("Сортируем массив методом пузырька. Средний уровень, 4 задание");
        Console.WriteLine("Введите длину массива = ");
        // Преобразуем заполненную в консоле n в int
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        // Заполняем массив с данными
        int[] a = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("A[{0}]=", i);
            a[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        // Метод пузырька - попарно сравниваем цифры и ставим наибольшее в конец до момента, последнее число не будет больше, чем другие
        for (int k = n - 1; k > 0; k--)
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
                {
                    buf = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[i + 1];
                    a[i + 1] = buf;
                }

        // Отчищаем консоль от введенных данных
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Отсортированный массив: ");

        // Вывод информации на экран консоли
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("[A{0}] = {1}", i, a[i]);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Нужно направление, как реализовать нечто подобное? Я так понимаю, нужно создать поток и передать в него функцию, которая будет выполняться уже в потоке

Comment: В природе не существует многопоточных сортировок "пузырьком". Но вы, конечно можете запустить её, например в фоновом потоке.

Comment: Но разве нельзя сделать так, чтобы 1-ый поток считал одну половину массива, а 2-ой другую? В сети находил пример, где подобная штука была реализована для алгоритма поиска минимального значения массива

Comment: алгоритм параллельной сортировки пузырьком есть во множестве источников в интернете, грубо говоря, смысл в том, чтобы разбить массив на n частей, отсортировать параллельно на n потоках, потом объединять соседние части "снизу" и снова сортировать, потом объединять соседние части "сверху" и так у вас будут чередоваться две эти итерации, и постепенно все "пузыри всплывут". Создайте общую функцию сортировки, и загоняйте в неё в правильном порядке "части" массива.

Comment: Для минимального - можно сделать, для сортировки - нет. Судите сами: после окончания 2 потоков у Вас будет половина сортированного массива и 2 половина тоже сортирована, только после конца первой половины, у Вас будет граничное значение второй(например минимальное, если сортировка по возрастанию). В итоге, после такой сортировки придётся ещё раз сортировать. Есть другие способы сортировок, которые позволяют использовать многопоточность.

Comment: у меня был где-то код на openmp, потому что именно с помощью многопоточности это будет выглядеть отвратно) если нужен, то можете открыть почту в профиле, я отправлю исходники) реальный профит во времени будет только на больших данных и на 5-10 потоках +- смотря какой у вас пк/кластер

Comment: Буду не против исходника) Интересно будет пошариться. Не нашел, где можно открыть почту, поэтому скину здесь - kross878@mail.ru